# Unable to extract information from Linux shell command using python

Tags: python

I am creating a Python script to collect data on underlying hardware from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
I am trying to extract information i need. But I am having a problem. Here is the script

```
import os
p=os.popen ("cat /proc/cpuinfo")
string=[]
i=0
for line in p.readlines():
   string.append(line.split(":"))
   if(string[i][0]=='model name'): 
        fout = open("information.txt", "w")
        fout.write("processor:")
        fout.write(string[i][1])
        fout.close()
   i+=1
```

My program does not enter if loop at all why? Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2):

There is no point to use `cat` at all here.  Refactor it like this:

```
with open("/proc/cpuinfo") as f:
  for line in f:
    # potato potato ...
```

Answer (score 1):

it probably does enter the loop but there might be a whitespace around "model name". You could call `.strip()` to remove it.

You can open `/proc/cpuinfo` as a file:

```
with open("/proc/cpuinfo") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, sep, value = line.partition(":")
        if sep and key.strip() == "model name":
           with open("information.txt", "w") as outfile:
               outfile.write("processor:" + value.strip())
           break
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what exactly is wrong. I could not figure that out at a glance, though on my Ubuntu 12.10 it also fails in the same way. Anyway, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module since `popen` is deprecated.

`subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/proc/cpuinfo'])` returns a string quite successfully, at least on my system. And `subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/proc/cpuinfo']).split('\n')` will give you a list you may iterate through.

Also note that `string[i][0]=='model name'` won't work. There are tabs after splitting that line by `':'`. Do not forget to call `strip()`: `string[i][0].strip()=='model name'`

Then, on Python 2.6+ (or even 2.5+, though 2.5 requires `from __future__ import with_statement`) it's almost always a good practice to use `with` for dealing with a file you need to open:

```
with open("information.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write("processor:")
    fout.write(string[i][1])
```

And finally, those saying you may just open a file and read it, are quite right. That is the best solution:

```
with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as f:
    #Here you may read the file directly.
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing it as :

```
for line in p.readlines():
    line=line.split(":")
    if(line[0]=='model name\t') :
            #Do work
```

If you dont need the complete list `string`.